# If a lamb gets lost in a flax field, does it become shatnez?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

What do Sha'ul Hamelech (before he was king) and Little Bo Peep have in common? Their sheep got lost.

If their, or someone's sheep got lost in a flax field, and rolled around or ate some of the flax, is it now possible that since the sheep has wool, that sheep might now be shatnez? If so, how would you get rid of the shatnez, if you could?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 2):

Well, your supposition that the sheep might become shatnez is very well established. The principle of "you are what you eat" is firmly grounded in halacha, to the extent that there is a machlokes regarding one who is cholev on shabbos - they may be engaging in kotzer since a cow eats grass and therefore may be considered to have grown from the ground!

Fortunately, you are only chayiv if you intentionally leave your sheep there until it is hosif bimatayim.

If we assume that the sheep is now, in fact, shatnez, then we can assume the method of its elimination is identical to that of kilayim in a field (again, you are what you eat) - shotrim from beis din remove the kilayim from the field directly (see maseches kilayim), or in this case: shear the sheep.

However, owners of kilayim and shatnez began to rejoice at the free labor provided by beis din. (ibid) As a result, they instituted a change - not ONLY would they be meva'er the kilayim (and boy does burning wool stink!), they would ALSO be makdish the sadeh. You would be sans-sheep.

You should have thought twice before trading your sheep for wheat.